# Maven resource filtering - ignoring outside class declaration

Tags: java, maven, resources, filtering

I'm trying to use maven resource filtering to replace a text within a java class.
At this moment, I'm only partially succeeded, i.e., I have a java class that has the same placeholder on two places. Running maven install, it replaces correctly the one inside java class, but not the one declared in a class java anotation.

Below is the relevant part of my class:

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "Support", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", wsdlLocation = "${java.wsdlLocation}" )
public class Support extends Service {

   private final static URL SUPPORT_WSDL_LOCATION;
   private final static WebServiceException SUPPORT_EXCEPTION;
   private final static QName SUPPORT_QNAME = new  Name("http://tempuri.org/", "Support");

   static {
       URL url = null;
       WebServiceException e = null;
       try {
           url = new URL("${java.wsdlLocation}");
       } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
           e = new WebServiceException(ex);
       }
       SUPPORT_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
       SUPPORT_EXCEPTION = e;
    }
```

And from the pom, I have:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Filter Java files -->
    <resource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <targetPath>../filtered-sources/java</targetPath>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.java</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>

<!-- change default source directory to filtered-sources/java -->
<sourceDirectory>target/filtered-sources/java</sourceDirectory>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Shouldn't resource filtering, make some kind of blind text replace, ignoring if it's a java class or not?
Is there any kind of limitation to resource filtering?

Comment: [Here you can see](https://github.com/khmarbaise/version-examples/tree/master/version-example-iv) how to use templating-maven-plugin to get working what you like to do.

Comment: @khmarbaise, is it possible, not to use a specific java-template package, and just point in to the specific class or subpackage? Sorry, but it doesn't "sound" me good, to separate it as a template, since it's not the purpose of this file to be a template.

Comment: The `java-template` is not a package it's just a folder where to locate those classes which should be filtered...

Comment: @khmarbaise, I understand it, it's a bit the same for me, and if I use a folder I need to maintain it as files, and not as code... it doesn't fit exactly my purpose... Anyway, I managed to get it working, as you  can see in my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not totally a solution, since I hadn't completely understood why this doesn't work as expected. However, after doing some tries, I kept changing the location of tags, and after some tries it worked.
This is how it ended up:

```
@WebServiceClient(
    name = "Support", 
    targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/",
    wsdlLocation = "${java.wsdlLocation}" )
public class Support extends Service {
```